# 15-17 significant decimal for binary64?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, decimal, ieee-754

I have learned from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) that a double number has at most 15-17 significant decimal digits

However, for the simple C++ program below

```
double x = std::pow(10,-16);
std::cout<<"x="<<std::setprecision(100000)<<x<<std::endl;
```

(To test it, use [this online shell](http://cpp.sh/3ymf) ), I get

```
x=9.999999999999999790977867240346035618411149408467364363417573258630000054836273193359375e-17
```

which has 88 significant decimal digits, which, apparently,  contradicts with the aforementioned claim from Wiki. Can anyone clarify should I misunderstand something? Thanks.

Comment: Most of those digits are *not* significant; most of them don't help distinguish this value from the next biggest or smallest possible `double` value.

Comment: @David: I voted to reopen (not realising that I have the casting vote due to my gold badge...); I believe that this isn't [the standard "why is FP broken?"-type question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken); it's asking about the apparent discrepancy between standard precision claims and the behaviour of `setprecision`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I believe it's the same old question which is, as always, about representability

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no contradiction. As you can see, the value of `x` is incorrect at the first `7` in its decimal expansion; I count 16 correct digits before that. `std::setprecision` doesn't control the precision of the inputs to `std::cout`, it simply displays as many digits as you request. Perhaps `std::setprecision` is poorly named, and should be replaced by `std::displayprecision`, but `std::setprecision` is doing its job. From a linguistic perspective, think of `std::setprecision` as setting the precision of `std::cout`, and not attempting to control the precision of the arguments to `std::cout`.